# Java Servlet SQLite JDBC Driver not found

Tags: java, sqlite, servlets, jdbc

I am trying to get data from a SQLite Db into my Servlet.

But I keep getting the Error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C://Users/Abc/Documents/sqlite/test.db

I am using Eclipse, Windows and Tomcat.
My source code looks like:

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
...
private void SQLite_Test() {
        try {

            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C://Users/Abc/Documents/sqlite/test.db";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM first");

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); 

            while ( rs.next() ) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt("id") +  "\t"+ rs.getString("name"));
                }
            conn.close();
          }catch..}

        protected void doGet(...
        {
          SQLite_Test();
          ...}
           ..}
```

I added the sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1 jar into the Classpath / Referenced Libraries and into Resources.

I tried it in a Java Project and it worked without problems.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you're still using a version of java/jdbc/etc. old enough to need `Class.forName()` to load the driver, it should probably be called *before* trying to use that class.

Comment: I don't need it in this version, I just tried it for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put the driver JAR into web-inf/lib.